# How to share readonly VkDeviceMemory for VkImages across VkInstances?

Tags: graphics, synchronization, gpu, vulkan

In my vulkan app, I use some VKImages to render something. The app may be started multiple times at the sametime, so there may be multiple instances of the program, each will have its own VkInstance.

What I want to do, is to **share the readonly VkImages** across VkInstances, so that I can greatly reduce the GPU memory footprint and increase cache performance. I want to know the right way to do it.

Since VkImage is backed by VkDeviceMemory, and Vulkan only supports VkDeviceMemory sharing by external memory extensions, I think I could share the memory objects as the following:

1. First, I start a **central** program S as a "memory pool" that manages the sharable memory objects.
2. When a VkImage is used by app instance A, it asks S to give it a memory object, by passing the VkImage's custom ID.
3. In S, if the ID is requested for the first time, it allocates the VkDeviceMemory and export a sharable handle back to A.
4. In A, a VkDeviceMemory is created by importing the handle and bind it to the VkImage object.
5. Next, A will initialize the content of the VkImage using a compute shader, which has the RGBA8 format by the way. Then, A CPU sync is performed, making sure the memory is initialized.
6. After some time, A app instance B is also request for the VkImage with the same ID. Then S returns the created sharable handle back to B, while telling B that the VKImage has been initialized already.
7. In B, A VkImage is created, VkDeviceMemory object is imported, but the VkImage's initialization is skipped.
8. Both in A and B, the VkImages will be used as normal textures to render something.

Note that when rendering, both A and B does no synchronization operations on the shared memory now.
When I test the app on several NVIDIA cards, everything works and no visible rendering errors are observed.

However, it's wrong when I test the app on AMD cards. It seems that A's rendering seems fine, but in B, the content of the image is incorrectly arranged. The image seems to be divided into blocks and rotated separately:

[Process A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TbS0.png)

[Process B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAck7.png)

So here are my questions:

1. Why does this happen? Is it due to the lacking of synchronization between A, B and S? If so, how to make it right exactly.
2. Why no visual errors at all on NVIDIA cards?

Comment: "*When a VkImage is used by app instance A, it asks S to give it a memory object, by passing the VkImage's custom ID.*" This presumes a 1:1 correspondence between memory and images. Don't do that. You may not be able to make as many memory allocations as you can images. "*Why no visual errors at all on NVIDIA cards?*" Your probably got "lucky".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In fact I simplify the situation in the description. In S I indeed use vma to sub-allocate memory. Also, I agree with you that I got 'lucky' on NVIDIA cards. I just don't know how to do it the right way. I believe Vulkan as a low-level graphics api, read-only image sharing across VkInstances(processes) should be a valid and powerfull usage.

Comment: See VK_KHR_external_memory for how to export/import memory handles for Vulkan objects.